# Making an Android build with my game works perfectly, however building the same game for PC causes every skinned/bone element to not be rendered

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering, skinning

I've created a game in Unity 2018.3.12f1

No matter which platform I'm working on, PC or Android, within the Editor the game runs perfectly.

When I create an android build, .APK the game runs perfectly as intended

When I create a PC build the game is run as intended EXCEPT all the graphics that are based on skinning/bone (using the build in skinning editor) don't render, they are just invisible.

**Android Image**
[image: Android Image]

**PC Image**
[image: PC Image]

**Sometimes its not invisible but shows as artifacts**
[image: Artifacts PC]

Tested in PC, WEBGL and Android, only android works correctly, PC and WEBGL are the same, invisible skinned/bone rigged models

Sent the file to other people who confirmed the android build works correctly and have the same issues with the pc/webgl build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling with numerous options and builds, the thing that seems to fix this issue is **changing the compression method** for the **specific models** in questions from **normal to high**